# How to keep value of check box saved when page reload?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty figuring out how to keep the toggle button yes or no in localStorage even when pages refresh. I also want to keep checked or unchecked the toggle button. Note: I have also tried to use autocomplete="false" but it's not worked that way as well. Anyone can help me? Many Thanks.

HTML

```
<h1 id="marker" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom:50px;"></h1>
<label class="label-switch switch-primary">
<input type="checkbox" class="switch switch-bootstrap status" name="status" id="status" 
onclick="yesno() ">
```

JS code

```
 function yesno(){
   let status = document.getElementById("status");

   if(status.checked == true)
   {
    localStorage.setItem("isChecked", true);
    status.checked = true;
    location.reload();
   } 
   if(status.checked == false)
   {
    localStorage.setItem("isChecked", false);

   } 

 }
 marker.innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("isChecked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-cookies-2m4t0?file=/index.html) with the solution you are looking for.

I left the markup untouched, but changed the function to this:

```
function yesno() {
    let statusEl = document.getElementById("status");
    localStorage.setItem("isChecked",JSON.stringify(statusEl.checked));
    const marker = document.getElementById("marker");
    marker.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("isChecked");
}
```

And added the following function to mark the checkbox as checked if needed when the page loads:

```
function onInit() {
    const isChecked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isChecked"))
    document.getElementById("status").checked = isChecked
}
```